# How to put auth functionality in @app.before_request in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-jwt-extended, flask-jwt

I want to make auth layer in flask app . I was using flask-jwt-extended for jwt auth so for that i have to mentioned @jwt_requied decorator for each protected route . so i dont want to do that for each protected route. I thought to define a function and make that to execute before each request by using @app.before_request. i want auth to happen in this layer.

```py
def check_user_token():
    if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
        token = request.headers['x-access-token']
    if not token:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing'}), 401

    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        current_user = UserDetails.query.filter_by(username=data['username']).first()


    except:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Token is in-valid'}), 401
return current_user
```

So this the function i want to call before each request to check auth.

```
@app.before_request
def before_calback():
    #want to call that check_user_token() from here and 
   #also dont want to call that for 'login' route .
   #Once i will get some response from check_user_token() 
   #based on that want to proceed further
  #and  here i dont know to do this.
```

Basically my qns is how to do authentication in @app.before_request def before_calback() ?

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Why not make a custom decorator and put in on the endpoints you want to protect?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access check_user_token()?

It would be like this

```
@app.before_request
def before_calback():
    check_user_token()
```

If you can post the some code, it would be easier to help you.